# A Question about derivative.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $f(0)= 0$, and $f’(x) > f(x)$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f(x) > 0$ for $x >0$. 
Clear, $f'(0)> 0$ and by defintion, $f'(0)> f(0)=0$.
Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Remember that $f'(x)>0$ means that $f$ is increasing.   Proceed from there

Comment: @Alan: It is given that $f'(x) > f(x)$ and not that $f'(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$ so that $g'(x) = e^{-x}\{f'(x) - f(x)\} > 0$ for all $x$. And clearly $g(0) = f(0) = 0$. Since $g$ is strictly increasing it follows that $g(x) > g(0) = 0$ for all $x > 0$. Thus $f(x) = e^{x}g(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to argue by contradiction. Call $a= \inf \{ x \in (0, \infty) : f(x) \le 0\}$. If $a>0$, obviously (by continuity arguments) you have $f(a)=0$. Then in the interval $[0,a]$ you can apply Rolle's Theorem, and get a contradiction.

Comment: Can you also say $a>0$ since $f^{\prime}(0)>0$?

Comment: Oh yes! As you say, this is important, because it could be that $a=0$ using only my argument.