# If $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all reals and $f(x_{0})=0$, then $f(x)>0$ for $x>x_{0}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Someone had asked an interesting question but deleted it after one
hour. Since the question is interesting, I will re-post it and submit a
full solution.

---

**Question:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable
function such that $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose
that there exists $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_{0})=0$, prove
that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>x_{0}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463120/a-question-about-derivative?noredirect=1

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576874/42969

Comment: The recent question was deleted by its author because it is a *duplicate.* Your solution has also been given before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1463147/42969.

Comment: @ Martin R Do you mean Crostul's solution? That solution is a draft and does not say anything when $a=0$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)\implies g(x_0)=0$. Since $g(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)>f(x),$
$$g'(x)=e^{-x}\left(f'(x)-f(x)\right)>0$$
Therefore, $g(x)$ is strictly increasing and $g(x)>0,\;\forall x>x_0$.
Also, $$f(x)=e^xg(x)>0$$
for all $x>x_0$.

Comment: Correct, but not new. This has been asked and answered several times before.

Comment: I was aware that the question had been asked before. This might sound silly, but every question was a special case $(x_0=0)$. But you are right, the proof is essentially  the same.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x)=f(x+x_{0})$.
Clearly, $g$ is differentiable and for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $g'(x)=f'(x+x_{0})>f(x+x_{0})=g(x)$.
$g(0)=f(x_{0})=0$. We go to prove by contradiction that $g(x)>0$
for all $x>0$. Suppose that there exists $x>0$ such that $g(x)\leq0$.

Define $A=\{x\in(0,\infty)\mid g(x)\leq0\}$. Since $A$ is non-empty
and bounded below by $0$, $\xi:=\inf A$ exists. Firstly, we show
that $\xi=0$. Prove by contradiction. Suppose that $\xi>0$. Choose
a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $A$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow\xi$. Since
$g$ is continuous and $g(x_{n})\leq0$, by letting $n\rightarrow\infty$,
we have that $g(\xi)\leq0$. By Mean-Value Theorem, where exists $c\in(0,\xi)$
such that $g(\xi)-g(0)=g'(c)(\xi-0)$. Hence, $g(c)<g'(c)=\frac{g(\xi)}{\xi}\leq0$
because $g(\xi)\leq0$ and $\xi>0$. Therefore $c\in A$. However,
$c<\xi$, contradicting to the fact that $\xi$ is a lower bound of
$A$. This shows that $\xi=0$.

Since $\xi\notin A$, we can choose a strictly decreasing sequence
$(x_{n})$ in $A$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow\xi=0$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & g'(0)\\
 & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(x_{n})-g(0)}{x_{n}-0}\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(x_{n})}{x_{n}}\\
 & \leq & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
because $g(x_{n})\leq0$ while $x_{n}>0$. On the other hand, $g'(0)>g(0)=0$,
which is a contradiction.

Comment: For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x + x_0) = 0$?